# How to find percentage difference in values between two consecutive dates and skip if dates not consecutive?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which for which I looks like this

```
date    mem
2018-03-09 13:27:05 23
2018-03-09 13:27:13 22
2018-03-09 13:54:34 21
2018-03-10 13:54:42 12
2018-03-10 16:18:34 34
2018-03-10 16:18:41 45
2018-03-12 22:40:36 45
2018-03-12 22:40:36 12
2018-03-14 22:40:44 35
2018-03-14 22:40:44 25
2018-03-15 23:12:36 26
2018-03-15 23:12:44 28
2018-03-15 23:22:34 12
2018-03-15 13:27:05 14
2018-03-16 13:27:13 54
2018-03-16 13:54:34 12
2018-03-16 13:54:42 56
2018-03-17 16:18:34 45
2018-03-18 16:18:41 76
2018-03-18 22:40:36 56
2018-03-18 22:40:44 23
2018-03-18 23:12:36 22
2018-03-18 23:12:44 24
2018-03-19 23:22:34 23
```

Now I want to find the percentage difference in stats(mean, min, max, std) between two consecutive dates and create a column with that value.

Now I can find the percentage difference between two given dates manually.Here is my code below

```
df = pd.read_csv("metrics.csv", parse_dates=["date"])

df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

df_prev = df.loc['2018-03-09'].resample('D')['mem'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

df_next = df.loc['2018-03-10'].resample('D')['mem'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

df_diff_pt = abs(df_next - df_prev.values)/(df_prev.values) * 100
print(df_diff_pt)
```

How do I do it on an automated manner where it finds the percentage difference in stats between two dates and skips the operation if the given date doesn't have a previous date?For example `2018-03-10` has a previous date `2018-03-9` but `2018-03-14` doesn't have a previous date so it should be skipped.However `2018-03-15` has a previous date `2018-03-14` so again it should find the stats difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if possible do it if before `resample`, but after is possible filter out all rows with `inf` only:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
df2 = df1.shift(freq='d').sub(df1).abs().div(df1).mul(100).iloc[:-1]
print (df2)
                   mem                                    
                  mean         min         max         std
date                                                      
2018-03-09         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2018-03-10   27.472527   75.000000   48.888889   94.048603
2018-03-11         inf         inf         inf         inf
2018-03-12  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2018-03-13         inf         inf         inf         inf
2018-03-14  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2018-03-15   50.000000  108.333333   25.000000   13.397460
2018-03-16   50.819672    0.000000   50.000000   67.137961
2018-03-17    9.629630   73.333333   24.444444         inf
2018-03-18   11.940299  104.545455   40.789474  100.000000
2018-03-19   74.782609    4.347826  230.434783         inf
```

---

```
#compare if not equal inf
mask = df2 != np.inf
print (mask)
              mem                     
             mean    min    max    std
date                                  
2018-03-09   True   True   True   True
2018-03-10   True   True   True   True
2018-03-11  False  False  False  False
2018-03-12   True   True   True   True
2018-03-13  False  False  False  False
2018-03-14   True   True   True   True
2018-03-15   True   True   True   True
2018-03-16   True   True   True   True
2018-03-17   True   True   True  False
2018-03-18   True   True   True   True
2018-03-19   True   True   True  False
```

---

```
#check if at least one True per row
print (mask.any(axis=1))
date
2018-03-09     True
2018-03-10     True
2018-03-11    False
2018-03-12     True
2018-03-13    False
2018-03-14     True
2018-03-15     True
2018-03-16     True
2018-03-17     True
2018-03-18     True
2018-03-19     True
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

---

```
#filter by boolean indexing
df2 = df2[mask.any(axis=1)]
print (df2)
                   mem                                    
                  mean         min         max         std
date                                                      
2018-03-09         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2018-03-10   27.472527   75.000000   48.888889   94.048603
2018-03-12  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2018-03-14  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2018-03-15   50.000000  108.333333   25.000000   13.397460
2018-03-16   50.819672    0.000000   50.000000   67.137961
2018-03-17    9.629630   73.333333   24.444444         inf
2018-03-18   11.940299  104.545455   40.789474  100.000000
2018-03-19   74.782609    4.347826  230.434783         inf
```

Comment: hey ideally there should be 2018-03-10 since 2018-03-09 is there so its consecutive but no 2018-03-11 since it doesn't exists and then directly 2018-02-15 since 2018-02-14 exists and its consecutive and so on..

Comment: @SouvikRay - Answer was changed, mainly `shift` is apply first and then compared with original `df`, so fiinally filter out rows with `2018-03-11`  and `2018-03-13`.